# Is it possible to Change App Icon after the App is Approved

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have submitted a App and now I want to update it by changing the App icon.
So Is it possible to Change App Icon after the App is Approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the app with new Icon. Create a new version of the app, update the App icon and submit again.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You will have to submit the App again. However, I suggest you try and request an [expedited review](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewteam/index.html), stating the only thing changed is the icon and state your reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)? If you don't want to go through the review process again, you could try to use the **Contact us** form in **iTunes Connect**, to get in touch with the review people at Apple. Maybe you would get the provision to change the App Store Icon.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**
only u can change in upgrade version